# Images from Sharepoint not Displaying in Teams

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I've created a Flow which takes items from a Sharepoint List and creates a message sent to a Teams channel by Webhook.

The message is based on the [Actionable Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/card-reference) type.

The connection works, but images hosted on OneDrive or in SharePoint don't show up. Images from external websites (like [TimyPulse from the sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUFkR.png)) do work.

Anyone know what I need to do to be able to show images?

Other questions/issues:

1. On Android app, the content of my first section is truncated.
2. On Android app, each section of the message is a swipe-able card.
3. On Android app, Link in Activity Subtitle works, but the link in the text doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Please don't post multiple questions within a single post.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply take a URI for a file from SharePoint or OneDrive and use it in your message. They are not a substitute for a web server.

You either need to host your images on a web server or convert them to base64 and use a [Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
data:image/png;base64,{base64 encoded image data}
```

Comment: Marc, 
Thank you very much for the direction. I have changed my List/Flow to now look for Attachments and then convert them to Base64. In Flow, the message generates perfectly, and I can verify it in the Card Playground. However, the Delivery to Teams does not work. The HTTP Post status code returns 200, but the body is "Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 413 with ContextId tcid=2621360276746394848,server=EAP010230119133,cv=NwLUXyVdN0uhKCant2X4fw.0.."
I have no idea what 413 is and googling Teams 413 doesnt point me in the right direction

Comment: It isn't `Teams 413`, its `HTTP 413`. This is the HTTP error status for  `Payload Too Large`. This is a different issue than the one you posted however. If you could make this as answered and post a new question, we can resolve this issue there.

Comment: Marc, I marked your response as Answered and posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199443/microsoft-flow-sharepoint-to-teams-http-413